# Changing Kendo UI MVC Command Buttons based on Security

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui

I have a Kendo Grid using Server binding and defined in a Razor view like @(Html.Kendo().Grid etc...

I'm using inline editing and it works find however I'd like to only show the destroy button if the user belongs to a certain role.

Any ideas about the best way to achieve this ? Ideally I'd like to write some sort of extension method so I could do something like :

```
columns.Command(command => { command.Destroy().If(IsInRole("Admin")) };
```

Any pointers would be very helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do it like this:

```
columns.Command(command =>
{
    if (IsInRole("Admin"))
    {
        command.Destroy();
    }
});
```